# Calculate Data Sparsity - There are no 'zeros'

Tags: r, categorical-data, sparse

I am being asked to provide the percentage of data sparsity in my dataset. The challenge I am running into is that there isn't traditional sparsity in my data, no 'zeros', 'NAs', '-' etc.. I am working with information related to clinic appointments and there are fields like "Not collected", "unknown", "Declined to provide" etc. Do I have to change all those to the same value and then calculate it that way?

During my initial research I kept coming into text classification examples and that's not what I am doing. I am working on a binary prediction and all my data is categorical, some ordinal, but most of it is unordered factors.

Anyone know a good package for R to calculate this once the data format questions is resolved?

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "data sparsity" and its potential relevance to the statistical problems you face?  In particular, you appear to describe data where (intuitively) the "sparsity" is 0%.  Why isn't that the answer?

Comment: Data Sparsity, to me, would be a measurement of missing data within a dataset. While my data does not contain zeros or NAs as I said there are other references to data that is not there. Should this be counted as if it was a missing value? Curious what others think on this topic.